# Retrofit/Android como hacer un GET que devuleva un integer

Tags: android-studio, api, retrofit

Hola tengo la siguiente peticion en mi API que  me devuelve un número int:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y en android Studio tengo lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi duda esta en que cuando realizado la llamada no me llega a devolver dicho número, pero tampoco soy capaz de capturar un error si lo hay. Directamente desde la línea selecciona se redirige al final del método.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

comentar que otro tipo de llamadas que me han devuelto objetos me han funcionado correctamente.

Comment: El código lo debes agregar como texto no como imagen.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres como texto? No estoy añadiendo ninguna imagen...